# How can I setup a relationship in RestKit when the only relationship info I have is the JSON structure?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I am trying to create a hierarchy of Node entities in Core Data based on a JSON I retrieve from a web service.

Here is a sample of my JSON structure

http://cl.ly/image/0r2x3E210m1U

I cannot figure out how to set up the relationships for the mapping.

Can someone please help me out? I am using the latest RestKit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
In JSON / RESTKIT you cant provide a recursive structure ob objects. 
try just to fetch an object level at once and make a new query if you like to dive deeper.

Your 'node' class should have a 'nodes' property with a kind of lazy-loading if someone access this property.

Comment: I kind of figured this one out. I ended up making my own parser.

Answer (score 0):

If this fails:

```
RKEntityMapping *nodeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Node" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[locationIconMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"name": @"name",
    @"type": @"type",
}];
[nodeMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"nodes" toKeyPath:@"nodes" withMapping:nodeMapping]];
```

Then how about:

```
RKEntityMapping *nodeMapping1 = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Node" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[nodeMapping1 addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"name": @"name",
    @"type": @"type",
}];

RKEntityMapping *nodeMapping2 = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Node" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[nodeMapping2 addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"name": @"name",
    @"type": @"type",
}];

[nodeMapping1 addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"nodes" toKeyPath:@"nodes" withMapping:nodeMapping2]];
[nodeMapping2 addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"nodes" toKeyPath:@"nodes" withMapping:nodeMapping1]];
```

Comment: yea, but for some reason, it maps to its self, meaning a Node instance 1 will map Node instance 1 as its parent and child.